# Ignoring lines with blank or space after character using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use sed to extract some assignments being made in a text file.  My text file looks like ...

```
color1=blue
color2=orange

name1.first=Ahmed
name2.first=Sam
name3.first=
name4.first=
name5.first=
name6.first=
```

Currently, I am using sed to print all the strings after the name#.first's ...

```
sed 's/name.*.first=//' file
```

But of course, this also prints all of the lines with no assignment ...

```
Ahmed
Sam




# I'm just putting this comment here to illustrate the extra carriage returns above; please ignore it
```

Is there any way I can get sed to ignore the lines with blank or whitespace only assignments and store this to an array?  The number of assigned name#.first's is not known, nor are the number of assignments of each type in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/^name[0-9]\.\w\+=\(\w\+\)/\1/p' file
```

### Output

```
Ahmed
Sam
```

### Explainations

- the `-n` switch suppress the default behavior of `sed` : printing all lines
- `s///` is the skeleton for a substitution
- `^` match the beginning of a line
- `name` literal string
- `[0-9]` a digit alone
- `\.\w\+` a literal dot (without backslash means any character) followed by a word character [a-zA-Z0-9_] al least one : `\+`
- `( )` is a capturing group and \1 is the captured group

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain your solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight variation on sputnick's answer:

```
sed -n '/^name[0-9]\.first=\(.\+\)/ s//\1/p'
```

The first part (`/^name[0-9]\.first=\(.\+\)/`) selects the lines you want to pass to the `s///` command. The empty pattern in the `s` command *re-uses* the previous regular expression and the replacement portion (`\1`) replaces the entire match with the contents of the first parenthesized part of the regex. Use the `-n` and `p` flags to control which lines are printed.